# Collapse searchview after submit

Tags: android, searchview

I am using searchview in my application ( without action bar). How can I collapse searchview after query text submit?

I have these listeners ;

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                            
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)thisFr.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(globalSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);
                            
            return false;
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
```

I don't use ActionBar so I don't have a function like collapseActionView().

Comment: You could probably call .setVisibility(View.GONE) on the search view - or is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: I second Cornholio for that, with an Animation you can achieve a nice looking collapse

Comment: Thanks for comments. But if you setVisibility to GONE , search icon will be invisible, too . isn't it ? I want to iconify search view.

Answer (score 19):

you need to call setIconified(true) twice to actually collapse your search view, with first call text is cleared with second call keyboard and search view get closed.

Answer (score 15):

You can do it this way in your activity, tested with actionbarsherlock (it even hides the keyboard, make sure to return false in onQueryTextSubmit):

```
private MenuItem searchMenuItem;

public MenuItem getSearchMenuItem() {
    return searchMenuItem;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // ...
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    // ...
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            MenuItem searchMenuItem = getSearchMenuItem();
            if (searchMenuItem != null) {
                searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // ...
            return true;
        }
    });
    // ...
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Just a note: This won't collapse the SearchView if a suggestion selected instead. You need OnSuggestionListener for that.

Comment: Looks like this is still the way to do it (6 yrs later)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the SearchView in the OptionsMenu, you ca call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

Answer (score 2):

```
//close suggestion list on query text submit
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final MenuItem searchterm = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = null;
     searchView = (SearchView) searchterm.getActionView();

     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            searchterm.collapseActionView();

}});
```